# use mutate to create new variable where column has one variable based on condition within tidy tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to create a new variable called cpi2000 that takes the cpi value of year 2000 for all observations in the series (i have four series hence the group_by) so that I can calculate an inflation adjustment factor. However, the following code only replaces the value for the year 2000 and leaves the other years as NA. Basically, I want there to be four numbers repeating in cpi2000, one for each series.

Here's the head of my data:

```
 Groups:   series_id [1]
  year  series_id value seasonal_adj        series_name                                     cpi2000
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>               <chr>                                             <dbl>
1 2000  CPIAUCSL   172. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.
2 2001  CPIAUCSL   177. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted     NA 
3 2002  CPIAUCSL   180. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted     NA 
4 2003  CPIAUCSL   184  seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted     NA 
5 2004  CPIAUCSL   189. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted     NA 
6 2005  CPIAUCSL   195. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted     NA 
>
```

```
cpi_values_tidy_clean <- cpi_values_tidy %>%  
 separate(date, 
          into = c("year"), 
          sep = "-", 
          extra = "drop") %>%                                                            # separate NAM into three variables 
  group_by(series_id) %>%  
  mutate(cpi2000 = if_else(year == 2000, value, value[2000])) %>%  
  glimpse()
```

Here's the output:

```
[1] 172.192      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 172.200      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
[36]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 165.717      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 165.725      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
[71]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I figured the best way to do this was with an if_else statement (case_when didn't seem to work). This would work if I could figure out how to get the second argument in the if_else statement ("value[2000]) to take value when year == 2000 as well,  but I can't figure out how to specify a condition on the second statement.

The end goal is create two variables cpi2000 and cpi2019 so I can create a third variable cpi_adj = (cpi2019/cpi2000) that can  be used as an inflation factor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your data by copying the output of `dput(cpi_values_tidy)` into your question. If your dataset is big then do `dput(head(cpi_values_tidy))`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can specify the year in the second condition value[year == 2000] instead of subsetting the bracket position like i was with value[2000]. Subsetting the using 2000 produced the "NA's" because there wasn't  a 2000th row, instead I would use value[1] because I want the first value. Alternatively, filtering on year is safer because it allows me to specify the year I want. Here's the code and output below I settled with:

```
cpi_values_tidy_clean <- cpi_values_tidy %>%  
 separate(date, 
          into = c("year"), 
          sep = "-", 
          extra = "drop") %>%                                                            # separate NAM into three variables 
  group_by(series_id) %>%  
  mutate(cpi2000 = if_else(year == 2000, value, value[year == 2000])) %>%  
  mutate(cpi2019 = if_else(year == 2019, value, value[year == 2019])) %>%  
  glimpse()

  head(cpi_values_tidy_clean)
```

```
 year  series_id value seasonal_adj        series_name                                     cpi2000 cpi2019
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>               <chr>                                             <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2000  CPIAUCSL   172. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.    256.
2 2001  CPIAUCSL   177. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.    256.
3 2002  CPIAUCSL   180. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.    256.
4 2003  CPIAUCSL   184  seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.    256.
5 2004  CPIAUCSL   189. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.    256.
6 2005  CPIAUCSL   195. seasonally adjusted US city average, all items, seasonally adjusted    172.    256.
```

If anyone knows how to do this more elegantly or with case_when, I'd love to see it.

Comment: When you run your code there is a warning message. Have you check it?